# scrolling issue on html webpage

Tags: html, css

This is my code, HTML and body has body class,and then inside them a  div has a background image and inside that a div has  color overlay and at last there is a login form inside them. I have  scrolling in my page, how can I remove it and have a page without scrolling.It is important for me that be correct in all media size.

```css
.bg-image{
  background: url("../images/666664.jpg") ;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white!important;
}

.color-overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d235b;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<html  class="body">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="body">
    <div class="bg-image">
      <div class="color-overlay"></div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <form class="login form_height col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input placeholder="Username" type="text" class="form-control" id="staticEmail">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="sub_btn" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" ></label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn login_btn btn-default btn_sub " value="Login" id="sub_btn" >
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="col-xs-12 no-padd"></footer>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that because the `form`/ `.container` is outside of the `.color-overlay` div it is not working as expected.

```css
.bg-image{
  background: url("../images/666664.jpg") red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white!important;
}

.color-overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d235b;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<html  class="body">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="body">
    <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="container">
        
        <div class="color-overlay">
        <div class="row">
        <form class="login form_height col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input placeholder="Username" type="text" class="form-control" id="staticEmail">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="sub_btn" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" ></label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn login_btn btn-default btn_sub " value="Login" id="sub_btn" >
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="col-xs-12 no-padd"></footer>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it does't  work because cover-overlay will cover my entire page include the form

Comment: @elahe edited the answer. You can just play around with the order of divs. If that is not what you're looking for you should describe the result with what you want in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `<div class="container">...</div>` inside `<div class="color-overlay"></div>` - that must fix your problem.